# changing position of a bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I want to ask if anyone knows how to center a bootstrap navbar.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Geographical location</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and I changed the width of the navbar so it fits better a doesn't have have lot of unused space there but its glued to the left side and i would love to center it.

CSS

```
.navbar-default {

width:38.5%;}
```

Comment: @CBroe I know you think I'm retarded but i already ask that guy you know. I wouldn't be asking here if I didn't ask my best friend first ;)

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry that my question is triggering you, thanks for the tips tho will try to ask better next time c:

Answer (score 0):

Try This. This should do it

```
.navbar-default {
 margin-left:auto; 
 margin-right:auto;
 width:38.5%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Geographical location</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Also codepen example: https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/eewpWO